# Passing variable values into another if condition

Tags: php

Here is my code and i need to insert array values in $testar in to the table patients_testings. But it doesn't work with this code, where is the error? if i can do this using one global variable. it will be more helpful. thank you.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="" name="testing" onsubmit="return validate_form()">
    <?php
    $sqltestin = "SELECT * FROM testings";
    $querytestin = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sqltestin);
    while ($rowtestin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytestin)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="testingar[]" value="' . $rowtestin['TestId'] . '">' . $rowtestin['TestName'] . '<br>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submittestin" id="submittestin" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Tests">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>


<?php
$checkBox = '';
$testar = '';
if (isset($_POST['submittestin'])) {
    global $checkBox;
    global $testar;
    $checkBox = $_POST['testingar'];

    foreach ($checkBox as $testar1) {
        $testar .= $testar1 . ",";
    }
    $tot = 0.00;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($checkBox); $i++) {
        $queryt2 = "SELECT * FROM testings WHERE TestId = $checkBox[$i] ";

        $resultt2 = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $queryt2) or die (mysql_error());
        while ($rowt2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt2)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $rowt2['TestName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='100'>" . $rowt2['specimen'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowt2['HopePrice'] . "</td></tr>";
            //echo  '<br/>';
            $tot = $tot + $rowt2['HopePrice'];

        }

    }

    echo "<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td <b>:</b></td><td><b>" . number_format($tot, 2) . "</b></td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td><form role='form' method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='printinv' id='printinv' class='btn btn-success' value='Print'></form></td></tr>";

    //echo $testar;
    if (isset($_POST['printinv'])) {
        $sqltnum = "INSERT INTO patients_testings VALUES ('$ref_no','$testar')";
        if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sqltnum) or die (mysql_error())) {
            echo "Entered Successfully";
            //}
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What did you examine yourself?

Answer (score 0):

### Why your code does not work:

I think the concept that you are missing is that when the page is requested, and on every subsequent form submission, the PHP code is executed then exits which throws out the values of the variables stored in memory. Making the variables global does not make them persist between requests.

### Specifics to your code:

The first time the form is submitted `isset($_POST['submittestin'])` is `true` and it successfully populates the `$testar` variable with data. However, on the second post `isset($_POST['submittestin'])` is `false` and so you never hit the `if (isset($_POST['printinv']))` section. Now, even if you move the `if (isset($_POST['printinv']))` outside the first `if ... submittestin` you still have a problem because the `$testar` will no longer be populated with data.

Additionally, you use variables which are never initialized anywhere that I can see. `$ref_no` is an example.

I would also suggest `echo`ing out your DB queries to see if they are properly formatted before you run them. I think that some of them may be missing `'`s in places.

### How to make data persist between requests?

The best way is to start a session. By starting a session you can save variables in the `$_SESSION` array and then access them durring a different request.

Note: You cannot serialize `resorces` so you will need to reconnect to the database on each request. I.e., this won't work: `$_SESSION['dbhandle'] = $dbhande;`

Another way to set `<input type=hidden ...` elements in your form so that on the second post you can access them again through the `$_POST` variable.

### Attempt to make your code use sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form role="form" method="post" action="" name="testing" onsubmit="return validate_form()">
    <?php
    $sqltestin = "SELECT * FROM testings";
    $querytestin = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sqltestin);
    while ($rowtestin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querytestin)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="testingar[]" value="' . $rowtestin['TestId'] . '">' . $rowtestin['TestName'] . '<br>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submittestin" id="submittestin" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Tests">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>


<?php
$checkBox = '';
$testar = '';
if (isset($_POST['submittestin'])) {
    global $checkBox;
    global $testar;
    $checkBox = $_POST['testingar'];

    foreach ($checkBox as $testar1) {
        $testar .= $testar1 . ",";
    }

    $_SESSION['testar'] = $testar;
    $_SESSION['ref_no'] = "This gets used below but I don't see it initialized anywhere?";

    $tot = 0.00;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($checkBox); $i++) {
        $queryt2 = "SELECT * FROM testings WHERE TestId = '".$checkBox[$i]."'"; // syntax issue here 

        $resultt2 = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $queryt2) or die (mysql_error());
        while ($rowt2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt2)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $rowt2['TestName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width='100'>" . $rowt2['specimen'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowt2['HopePrice'] . "</td></tr>";
            //echo  '<br/>';
            $tot = $tot + $rowt2['HopePrice'];

        }

    }

    echo "<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td <b>:</b></td><td><b>" . number_format($tot, 2) . "</b></td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td><form role='form' method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='printinv' id='printinv' class='btn btn-success' value='Print'>";
    echo "</form></td></tr>";
}

    //echo $testar;
    if (isset($_POST['printinv'])) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['testar']) {
            $testar = $_SESSION['testar'];
            $ref_no = $_SESSION['refno'];
            $sqltnum = "INSERT INTO patients_testings VALUES ('$ref_no', '$testar')"; // Where is $ref_no set?
            if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sqltnum) or die (mysql_error())) {
                echo "Entered Successfully";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind support. But still the session value of testar cant be used inside the if condition. ref_no has been declared earlier and its value is passed to the table.